# Can utter be substituted infinite, when describing love?

Tags: meaning

Utter is a verb and an adjective. It means something is without qualification from the explanation of the internet. Can I use this word as utter love, which is as the substitution for infinite love?

Comment: Have you checked for actual usage, for example, using [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=utter+love%2Cabsolute+love%2Cinfinite+love&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cutter%20love%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cabsolute%20love%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinfinite%20love%3B%2Cc0)?

Comment: Chris de Burgh uses it, in [the worst song in the world](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/chrisdeburgh/theladyinred.html). So you should avoid it at all costs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> utter love
>
> My **utter** love for you.

may not be what you want to use, though it is understandable.

One of the properties of a BIG love is duration over time, so usually

> undying love
>   infinite love
>   everlasting love

get used when proclaiming love to express being boundless by time.

If a person is described as

> He is utterly in love with that girl.
>   *he is completely in love with that girl*

it usually means they are blind, all consumed, and may not listen to reason especially if *someone* is trying to warn them. "Utter" does not express the timeless dimension only the "focused" dimension.

Answer (score 2):

You would be understood if you used **utter** about love but, as this [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=utter%20love%2Cutter%20bliss%2C%20utter%20contempt%2Cutter%20disregard%2C%20utter%20poverty&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cutter%20love%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cutter%20bliss%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cutter%20contempt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cutter%20disregard%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cutter%20poverty%3B%2Cc0) shows, we tend to use the word **utter** in its adjectival sense about things that have quite strong negative connotations. Examples are contempt, disregard and poverty.